# Python indentation error on a line that doesn't exist

Tags: python

The code is as follows:

```
import glob
import os
import shutil

for file_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, '*Tomo*_[1-100]_*')):
    new_dir = file_path.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
    try:
      os.mkdir(os.path.join(folder, new_dir))
#shutil.move(file_path,os.path.join(new_dir,os.path.basename(file_path)))
```

The shutil command is currently commented out as this was causing a syntax error and I am not sure why. However when trying to run this I get an indentation error on line 10 (the code is 9 lines long). I am at a loss as to where I have gone wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just forgot the `except` clause:

```
import glob
import os
import shutil

for file_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, '*Tomo*_[1-100]_*')):
    new_dir = file_path.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
    try:
      os.mkdir(os.path.join(folder, new_dir))
    except Exception as e:
        pass
shutil.move(file_path,os.path.join(new_dir,os.path.basename(file_path)))
```

EDIT: As syntonym points, is not a good idea to just catch `Exception`, use the better exception handler for your job (In this case probable `FileExistsError`).

Comment: The catch-all exception is nearly always a bad idea, e.g. here it will also silence NameErrors (e.g. if one variable would be misspelled) or permission errors. It's better to only catch the exceptions one really wants to catch, so here probably FileExistsError.

Comment: @syntonym, exactly, but that is just up to him

Answer (score 0):

`try` statement is expecting an `except` statement after it.

You can change your code:

```
for file_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, '*Tomo*_[1-100]_*')):
    new_dir = file_path.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
    try:
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(folder, new_dir))
    except:
        print "Error joining path"
        # or simply
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is expecting `except` statement in `line 10`